# Incomplete configuration during ROS Hydro installation on OSX 10.9

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am an absolute beginner when it comes to ROS or Homebrew or even using the Terminal! Please bear with me here.

I've been following this tutorial (wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) to the letter trying to install ROS Hydro to my Mac OSX 10.9. I am stuck at section 2.1.3 where I'm told to run `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. Upon running it, the command fails with this error:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  Command 'cmake /Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && cmake /Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

Command failed, exiting.
```

I have no idea how I can continue installation from here, may it have something to do with the command `cmake /...Release` ending with `returned non-zero exit status 1`? Like I said, I'm an absolute beginner here and can't make sense of this or how to proceed.

I DID try running `brew doctor` and I was told my `system is ready to brew` with no warnings.

The rest of the installation up to this point was relatively smooth and was only met with one other major warning/error. At tutorial section 2.1.2 I'm told to resolve dependencies. I ran `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y` and at the end of the command I was asked my `sudo` password. I was met with this error:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL

Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow).

No distributions at all found for PIL.

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/.../pip.log

Error: the following rosdeps failed to install: pip: command [sudo pip install -U PIL] failed
```

Not sure if that's relevant or not but it does provide more detail on my situation. I could not find anyone else having the same problem, I have no idea if this is easily fixable or if this is a hard compatibility issue.

Please, if you can provide any insight, I would appreciate it very much. I can provide other details if needed. Thank you!!

edit 1: Using both William's and demmein's answers did solve my original PIL install issue. However, I still ended up getting stuck installing the rosdeps, mainly pcl. I dropped trying to install ROS on OSX 10.9 and installed it on Ubuntu and ran than on OSX through VirtualBox. I used a .ova file with ROS Hydro pre-installed and have been able to use it without issue since. Here is the link I used: (nootrix.com/downloads/#RosVM) (I used the 3.7 GB torrent). Thanks again everyone for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172900/incomplete-configuration-during-ros-hydro-installation-on-osx-10.9/) by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-06-09**:
I actually think it did solve your original issue, you just ran into a different, similar error later with PCL...

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-09**:
My original issue was not being able to run './src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' and I still wasn't able to run it and continue with the installation. But your answer and demmein's helped and definitely resolved the PIL issue. And they're both appreciated! (:

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-10**:
Feel free to post a new question with more details about the pcl issue. In general ROS on Ubuntu will be more of smooth sailing than on OS X, however some things don't always work great in a VM, such as visualization in rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The snippet you provided doesn't show the error, all of the interesting stuff would have happened above the `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!` line. Everything that follows is just letting you know that the build failed and how you can reproduce it manually if you so desired.

However, regardless of that error, the other snippet you posted probably indicates the issue with the CMake error. If you got `Error: the following rosdeps failed to install: pip: command [sudo pip install -U PIL] failed` then that means that not only was `PIL` not installed, but `rosdep` also didn't install any of the dependencies which followed. You can see what `rosdep` still needs to install (without actually installing anything) by running this command:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --simulate
```

Unless you get `#All required rosdeps installed successfully`, or nothing, back from `rosdep`, then you have unmet system dependencies still. I would imagine you have several, but at least `PIL`should be there.

You have one of two options, first you can figure out why `PIL` is not installing and install it manually, or you can tell `rosdep` to skip that dependency by adding `--skip-keys=python-imaging` (`python-imaging` is the `rosdep` key which resolves to `PIL` on `pip`).

I believe your `PIL` install error, gives you the solution:

```
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
```

So if you run this, it should probably install:

```
$ sudo pip install --allow-external -U PIL
```

Then you should be able to run `rosdep` again and get the rest of the dependencies. Once you have gotten all of your dependencies installed, you will probably be able to run `catkin_make_isolated`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-06**:
I really appreciate the reply, William! Your suggestion did not work seamlessly but it definitely pointed me in the right direction. I was able to install PIL 1.1.7. However, now when I try to run 'rosdep install –-from-paths /Users/jcRebanal/ros_catkin_ws/src –-ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y' ...

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-06**:
... I get "the following rosdeps failed to install: homebrew: command [brew install pcl] failed". I ran brew update then I ran brew doctor no problem. I tried to run 'brew install pcl' and I got the same issue. In the error it mentions "make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1" followed by ...

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-06**:
... a link to the github homebrew troubleshooting site. So it seems the rosdep 'brew install pcl' can't install and I'm stuck there now. My Xcode is updated and am looking for solutions right now!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-06-06**:
Not sure about the PCL problem, it might be worth a new question. Also in the future, you can update your question when comments are not big enough.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-06-07**:
If one of these answers resolves your original PIL question, please press the check mark. If you still have a problem with PCL, please open a new question, or ask on the pcl-users@pointclouds.org mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On top of what @William wrote, on 10.9 you probably also need the following patches before you can build all packages with `catkin_make_isolated`. Go to your workspace and execute the following

```
pushd src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
curl https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/pull/4.patch | patch -p1
curl https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/pull/19.patch | patch -p1
popd
 
pushd src/robot_model
curl https://github.com/ros/robot_model/pull/43.patch | patch -p1
popd
 
pushd src/robot_state_publisher
curl https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/5.patch | patch -p1
popd
 
pushd src/opencv2
curl https://github.com/ros-gbp/opencv2-release/pull/4.patch | patch
popd
```

And you should delete the `build` folder once after applying these patches to make sure there is no stale cmake configuration.

http://answers.ros.org/question/94771/building-ros-on-osx-109-solution/?answer=101176#post-id-101176

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc17](https://answers.ros.org/users/18797/jc17/) on 2014-06-06**:
Thank you for the reply demmein. The patches went without issue except the last one (opencv2), the terminal said "patch ends unexpectedly in middle of line". Also, exactly what build folder are you referring to? ~/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated ?? Sorry I'm so clueless about this sort of thing..!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-06**:
You can ignore that error about the last patch. It should still habe applied find. And yes, i was referrong to the build_isolated folder.